# IONIC 4, observable subscription is duplicating my html template

Tags: typescript, ionic4, subscribe

I'm using a service which return an observable to subscribe from any page to want to listen changes.

`FavoriteService.service.ts`:

```
favorites$ = new Subject<any>();

getObservableFavorite(): Observable<any> {
    return this.favorites$.asObservable();
}
```

I'm subscribing on dashboard page `DashboardPage.ts`:

```
favorites$: Observable<any>;
favoritesSubscription: Subscription;


constructor(private favService: FavoriteService){
  this.favorites$ = this.favService.getObservableFavorite();
  this.favoritesSubscription = this.favorites$.subscribe((data) => {
    // console.log('event received');
    this.favorites = data;
  });
}

// unsubscribe 
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.favoritesSubscription.unsubscribe();
}

// both, just in case 
ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.favoritesSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

My template is being duplicated and I don't know why!

```
<div *ngIf="favorites?.length > 0">
     <div class="img-thumb" *ngFor="let fav of favorites">
            <ion-card [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + fav?.background) + ')'">
            </ion-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

In other page like `MoviesPage` I send the subject `next()` event through the same service. As it:

```
  async makeFavorite(movie) {
      this.favMovies.push(movie)
      this.favService.favorites$.next(this.favMovies)
  }
```

I have debugged my code and when I get the event in dashboard, data is received without problem, but template is beign duplicated :/.

Could anyone help me? :)

Comment: If I remove **ngIf**, template is not being duplicated e.e, Does anyone has an idea what is happening?